# Registration help

Tags: 7, users

In drupal 7 I want to register function hook. when we click on register submit the values need to store in another database's table and with that inserted id need to store in user table. how we can write custom module for that

I wrote custom module like :

```
function hook_user_save($account, $edit = array(), $category = 'account') { // custom code

}
```

but it not working

Answer (score 0):

if you want to store the data during user registration try [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7)